# Qiskit - Authorization Required error

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

When I use Qiskit to do quantum computing, I suffer from a big problem.
When running the code,it turns out to be:

```
   {"error":{"name":"Error","status":401,"message":"Authorization Required",
   "statusCode":401,"code":"AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED"}}
```

It seems that I failed to authorize my account. I don't know how to get authorization. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you input your credentials ?

Comment: Could you paste the code that creates this error.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you run a code on one of IBM's Q.computers, you'll need to validate your access token which you can find in your IBM Q experience dashboard under the user category.
In case, you've done it beforehand but still doesn't seem to work, make sure to delete all your previous account details using

```
IBMQ.delete_accounts()
```

Then try regenerating a new access token, save the credentials and run again.

Or you could try reading the tutorials in IBM Q experience portal